# Table: Show only the first row of table tbody. How to hide the succeeding 1st rows?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html-table

The very 1st row of EVERY tbody is the row header (contains the column Names). *The rest of EVERY tbody succeeding 1st rows are not necessary and wanted to hide them.*

**Classes used:**

`toprowHeader` = 1st row that holds every column names

`recordsRow` = holds the other record details

**For now it shows like this:**

```
--------------------------------------------
| MessageID  |  Sender   | Message         |
--------------------------------------------
|         1  | admin     |my admin message |
--------------------------------------------
| MessageID  |  Sender   | Message         |
--------------------------------------------
|         2  | sender1   |reply to admin   |
```

**Here is the sample structure I wanted to achieve:**

```
--------------------------------------------
| MessageID  |  Sender   | Message         |
--------------------------------------------
|         1  | admin     |my admin message |
|         2  | sender1   |reply to admin   |
```

*Though I have some options to make it easier but the requirement says that every record should be inside a* **tbody**

Here is my Sample Table structure:

```
<table class="gridtable">
    <tbody>
            <tr class="toprowHeader" >
                <td class="">...</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="recordsRow " >
                <td class="">...</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="recordsRow " >
                <td class="">...</td>
            </tr>               

    </tbody>
    <tbody>
            <tr class="toprowHeader">
                <td class="">...</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="recordsRow ">
                <td class="">...</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="recordsRow ">
                <td class="">...</td>
            </tr>               
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

**Added requirement:**

A lot of you questioned the table structure above but the main reason why I placed it inside individual tbody its because I also have a button to be able to move the 1st tbody to the bottom/last of the table.

I use PHP to display records

Comment: `$('tr').not('.toprowHeader').hide()` will do that. Note that duplicated ID's is an error !

Comment: The above solution works, but you don't even need to have a toprowHeader class, you can just use CSS, the :nth-child pseudoselector,  something like this: tr:nth-child(n+1){display:none)

Comment: You can use CSS, but more importantly, you might be doing something weird.  Why are you creating multiple TBodys (why aren't the results in one query)? Why can't you limit the toprowHeader in the PHP? There are probably many better solutions.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dkz5h2dw/1/

Comment: as far as i have understand , it cant be done with css. as nth child works with respect to parent not as a whole on classed

Comment: @A.B http://jsfiddle.net/5xLpp5zg/ not possible? really?

Comment: @vol7ron with one selector :p 
well thats pretty nice btw :)

Comment: @A.B http://jsfiddle.net/5xLpp5zg/1/ one selector?

Comment: @vol7ron awsum, how can i join your class ;) (Y)

Comment: haha.  CSS is really ill-advised since they are CSS3 selectors and may not be supported by older browsers; for instance IE8, an old yet still prevalent browser.  For that reason, shaping the HTML response is a much better option.

Comment: but pretty good, i appreciate. every day i learn something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see output below ,Use this

It Will hide all the toprowHeaders except the first one as per your requirement

```js
                $('tr.toprowHeader:gt(0)').hide();
                $('table').append($('tbody:eq(0)'));
                console.log($('tbody:eq(0)'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="gridtable">
    <tbody>
            <tr class="toprowHeader" >
                <td class="">title 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="recordsRow " >
                <td class="">record1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="recordsRow " >
                <td class="">record1</td>
            </tr>               

    </tbody>
    <tbody>
            <tr class="toprowHeader">
                <td class="">title2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="recordsRow ">
                <td class="">record2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="recordsRow ">
                <td class="">record2</td>
            </tr>               
    </tbody> 
    <tbody>
            <tr class="toprowHeader">
                <td class="">title3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="recordsRow ">
                <td class="">record3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="recordsRow ">
                <td class="">record3</td>
            </tr>               
    </tbody> 
    <tbody>
            <tr class="toprowHeader">
                <td class="">title4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="recordsRow ">
                <td class="">record4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="recordsRow ">
                <td class="">record4</td>
            </tr>               
    </tbody> 
   <tbody>
            <tr class="toprowHeader">
                <td class="">title5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="recordsRow ">
                <td class="">record5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="recordsRow ">
                <td class="">record5</td>
            </tr>               
    </tbody> 
  <tbody>
            <tr class="toprowHeader">
                <td class="">title6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="recordsRow ">
                <td class="">record6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="recordsRow ">
                <td class="">record6</td>
            </tr>               
    </tbody>    
<tbody>
            <tr class="toprowHeader">
                <td class="">title7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="recordsRow ">
                <td class="">record7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="recordsRow ">
                <td class="">record7</td>
            </tr>               
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

Comment: Seems like you're right. If don't you mind, I would like to know as well how to move the 1st tbody to the bottom of the table jquery. That's I guess explain why I need to create another tbody rather than doing it once. I tried .appendTo() but it duplicates the 1st  tbody to the bottom. I need to move it. Result would be: the 1st tbody is moved and becomes the last. btw, I'm using a button to execute the moving of tbody.. thnx hope you can help..

Comment: @Raf do you want this? check code inspect element? edited my code

Comment: Thank you sir. I did a lot of search but your answer is much closer to what I'm lookin for.

Comment: One more thing sir.. This is not actually for you to answer but I just want to know if is it possible to dynamically add a button at the end of the table? Right now I'm doing it in php where each tbody has a button inside.. All I need is just show a button at the last tbody row.. I Will do the research if this is possible. Thanks a lot sir A.B

Comment: after all js line in last write this line
$("tbody").last().after("<button>your Button</button>")

Comment: this will work too 
$("table").append("<button>your Button</button>")

Comment: Everything was working.. now it becomes terrible.. I didn't change anything after it works.. now I'm getting error on every browser: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS .. I;ve search a lot, but it says its a chrome bug... but I don;t know really because every browser I tested has the same problem.. The issue is moving the 1st tbody to the bottom.. the rest are still working fine. Sorry, I;m just upset..

Comment: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS  isnt your headache leave it, and first tbody at last it what you said to have to me " I would like to know as well how to move the 1st tbody to the bottom of the table jquery." isnt it?

Comment: Yes that is right sir.. $('table').append($('tbody:eq(0)')); is working just lasted an hour only...Sorry to bother you again,..I've installed the beta version of latest google chrome that everyone is talking that has the fix..now, I got no error but still the problem persist.. The 1st tbody was not moved.. and I see something strange: I have 7 records but the 5th record was duplicated(not moved) to the last table and not the very 1st tbody..

Comment: @Raf look at the output i edited its working fine with 7 tbody items, actually what its doing is "Removing all title rows except the first one(that is in tbody number 1) then it is taking tbody no to the end of the table"

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS as shown below:

```css
tbody:not(:first-child) .toprowHeader{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table class="gridtable">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="toprowHeader">
      <td>Title</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="recordsRow ">
      <td>Record</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="recordsRow ">
      <td>Record</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="toprowHeader">
      <td>Title</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="recordsRow ">
      <td>Record</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="recordsRow ">
      <td>Record</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

By the way, You should really try modifying the script to omit the extra titles instead (whichever generates it), and have a single title row inside `<thead>`

Comment: Using `:first-of-type` instead of `:first-child` would be safer, because in the general case, the first `tbody` element need not be the first child of the `table` element. There can be a `caption` element`, `col` and `colgroup` elements, `thead`, and `tfoot` before it.

Comment: Is first-of-type as supported as first-child?  Again, the need to support older versions of IE will dictate need